# Pig unable to dump data from CSV

Tags: csv, hadoop, apache-pig, hortonworks-sandbox

I am using Pig to try to load and dump data from a csv that I uploaded onto Hortonworks Sandbox. However, after running the Pig scripts I got an error, and I am not sure why.

In Pig script editor within HortonWorks, I've typed the scripts below:

[image]

However, after running the script, it threw an error called 'Job job_1529984722769_0015 was failed'. I think my file path is correct as you can see from the screenshot below.

[image]

The CSV file is also comma separated as you can see from the preview below. (There is no column header in the csv but I am not sure if this is what is causing the error)

[image]

Also, I've tried running the LOAD script by itself and it was able to finish without any error. However, when I included the 'e_sample = limit e 10' and 'dump e_sample;' scripts, the error occurred.

Any suggestion is greatly appreciated!

Comment: you are missing / before user

Comment: Thanks, @Satya! A careless typo by myself. I added / and it worked as expected.

Comment: glad that I could help